# Using sortable with Tag-it jqueryui

Tags: jquery-ui, list, input, jquery-ui-sortable

I've been using the tag-it plugin from https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it (demo - http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/examples.html).

In this code there is an option to display the inputted tags in another input, textarea etc. First option -

```
        $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
            availableTags: sampleTags,

            singleField: true,
            singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField')
        });
```

Here the id - `#singleFieldTags` is the inputting field which is a list like `<ul` and id - `#mySingleField` displays the 'list-ordered' tags with commas between each.

All the tags that are added and removed in the `#singleFieldTags` appear in the `#mySingleField`. Since there is no built-it sortable function with tag-it, adding a `sortable()` to change the order of tags in `#singleFieldTags`, does not change the order of tags in `#mySingleField`.

The second option is a plain with only `#singleFieldTags` as follows :-

```
        $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
            availableTags: sampleTags,
        });
```

Although in tag-it.js there is a , the value does not appear in the mysql table after submitting the php form as the above list of tags is placed between `<li></li>`.

How is it possible to make the tags sortable and ensure that the same arrangement of tags in the list field `<ul` to be displayed in the `<textarea` as in First Option? Or How can the second option of sorting tags within a single field `<input` work and enabling it to be submitted by a form?

EDIT: There is a similar plugin like Tag-it called tagit here: http://webspirited.com/tagit/ . This plugin has sortable with an input box meaning if the tags were interchanged, and when submitted on form it would appear in the order of the sort. However, the disadvantage being that it has custom themeroller themes these are not similar and cannot even be linked to the ones at jQuery UI (jqueryui.com).

But on the other hand, the tag-it plugin (not tagit), can be loaded with these themes but does not provide the sortable function.

Comment: "Themeroller" (http://jqueryui.com/themeroller) is a part of JQueryUI. Tag-it plugin permits to load compatible JQUeryUI theme. So what is the problem to use the second plugin you found : Tag-it? You just need to specify the CSS file theme you are currently using in your site to the tag-it plugin or am I missing something?

Comment: I've tried `link href` ing to these(jqueryui.com/themeroller) themes but they don't work with tag-it as tag-it has predefined themes in a specific folder when you download it, the css file in these themes are very different from those at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller, and these don't even look as good as the original jQuery themeroller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the tag-it plugin, because I understand that your missing functionality is explained in your quote "*...adding a sortable() to change the order of tags in #singleFieldTags, does not change the order of tags in #mySingleField*".

In order to have "#mySingleField" reflect the new sort order, I'm adding a handler to the stop event of sortable():

```
$('#singleFieldTags').sortable({
    stop: function(event,ui) {
        $('#mySingleField').val(
            $(".tagit-label",$(this))
                .clone()
                .text(function(index,text){ return (index == 0) ? text : "," + text; })
                .text()
        );
    }
});
```

and

```
$('#singleFieldTags2').siblings(".tagit").sortable({
    stop: function(event,ui) {
        $('#singleFieldTags2').val(
            $(".tagit-label",$(this))
                .clone()
                .text(function(index,text){ return (index == 0) ? text : "," + text; })
                .text()
        );
        console.log( $('#singleFieldTags2').val() );        // just for reference
    }
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle that demonstrates the functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/KYQbf/2/)
(added functionality for single input field)

Comment: Yes this works good, will it be possible to have this feature for just one input field also? I am sure it wouldn't be that hard for you now that you have solved tag sort for 2 fields because it feels like the plugin would be incomplete or biased to only 2 fields suppose if at any point of time, I want to switch to plain input and find that those tags don't get sorted.

Comment: @Javier, yes, it was straightforward, I've added the sorting for the plain input field to the jsfiddle.